# How to transform data from on-premises sql/azure sql database in the cloud using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Suppose I have an SQL table as follows,

```
ID, Name, city
1, saran, Chennai
2, raj, Chennai
3, Kumar, NYC
```

suppose I wanna transform name from saran to raj, what component I have to use, because in Azure data factory I can see N number of components. Lets say azure databricks, u-sql, ect as data transform activity.

So please tell me that Which one I have to choose, if I have data from normal relational DB.

Comment: What do you mean transform name from saran to raj,  on-premise to Azure SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of those to transform the data, coding with whichever language/platform you prefer.

Or you can just design your transformations visually in ADF's Mapping Data Flows without any coding.